# How JVM is able to process simultaneously spring singleton code?

Tags: java, concurrency, jvm

I would like to ask you about how internally Spring Singleton will work in concurrency software. Please use as many details as you know. I want to know deply how JVM is resolve that.

I find similar question here - however that one concer two separate methods invoked by two separate thread - here I have one method and two threads

```
@Component 
public class SpringSingleton {

  public void justWait(){
     try {
        Thread.sleep(5000); 
     }
     catch(InterruptedException ex) {}
  } 
} 

@Component
public class StartClass {

   @Autowired 
   private SpringSingleton singleton; 

   public void runAfterAppStart(){
     for(int i=0; i<=1; i++){ 
         CompletableFuture.runAsync(() ->  singleton.justWait());
     }
   }
}
```

After running these piece of code, you'll see that two threads are end at almost same time.

**How it is possible? Why Thread2 doesn't have to wait until Thread1 will finish his work?**

As I understand whole flow, instance of SpringSingleton class will be placed on JVM Heap, then on stack Java will place two threads (Thread1,Thread2). Each of thread will contains own (independant) reference to Spring Singleton class - now...

Thread1 will use his reference to execute method "justWait". These method is obviously some instructions for processor. So if these instructions are currently   processes - how Thread2 is able to invoke them? 
The only explanation for me is, JVM will somehow copy byte code from heap to each thread - then everythink is clear - but it is really happening here?

Thank you for explanation of that problem. Even buzzwords which I can google will be really helpful

Comment: Take a cake recipe and pin it at a wall. How many bakers can process these instructions? As many as you have stoves or to incorporate pipeline architectures, there might be even more when some process dough while others use the stoves. The code, like the recipe, contains instructions which can get processed by as many processors as your hardware offers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How it is possible? Why Thread2 doesn't have to wait until Thread1 will finish his work?

Because you don't have any synchronisation going on.

> The only explanation for me is, JVM will somehow copy byte code from heap to each thread - then everythink is clear - but it is really happening here?

You're mixing up two things: instance variables and bytecode. Bytecode is the compiled Java code, and is present only once, and not on the heap. Instance variables are created on the heap, but each thread will have its own set.

In this example, however, there aren't any instance variables. So each thread simply runs the same bytecode. There is no need to wait, because bytecode doesn't change after it's been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not related to Spring Singleton implementation.

There are 3 threads. One main thread and 2 CompletableFuture threads. Main thread creates completable futures, finish it's work and application exits. It doesn't wait for the CompletableFuture to complete.

You can check this by adding additional Thread.sleep(10000) after the loop, for example:

```
    public void runAfterAppStart(){
     for(int i=0; i<=1; i++){ 
         CompletableFuture.runAsync(() ->  singleton.justWait());
     }
     // Hold main thread for the CompletableFuture to complete.
     Thread.sleep(10000);
   }
```

Comment: In addition:
 when Thread1 reaches `justWait()` method it goes to sleep and control passes to Thread2 which goes to sleep in its turn. Then after 5 seconds + some nanoseconds processor spent to switch control from Thread1 to Thread2 both threads terminate. What is a problem? This is exactly what threads are for. Just try to make sleep seconds random and you will see that threads terminate not at the "same" time...

Answer (score 0):

> Why Thread2 doesn't have to wait until Thread1 will finish his work?

1. Because threads are specifically made to do not wait one another.
   If you want one thread to wait until another completes use synchronized method or block.
2. Singleton methods are re-entrant, because actual code is in the class object.

Even if there are two non-singleton objects, still there is only one instance of code in the class.

3. When object(bean) is a singleton it means there is only one instance of that class and assigned memory for its data - instance variables.

> The only explanation for me is, JVM will somehow copy byte code from heap to each thread

it is wrong

BTW: in real there is no such thing as "simultaneously" it is just a matter of nanoseconds between thread switching...

Comment: "Non-static instance variables"... instance variables are always non-static, because they belong to an instance and not to a class.

Answer (score 0):

I can help with your last couple paragraphs--

There is just 1 copy of the code but both threads are able to run through it at the same time.  It's possible that both cores of a cpu are running through the code at EXACTLY the same time, but each CPU points to different data so that the exact same code might operate on different data.

In fact, one CPU may have data that evaluates to "true" another might evaluate to "false" so that an if() statement causes the threads to diverge.

The problem is there aren't enough CPUs so we have a way to save and restore the state of a single CPU so that it can act like multiple CPUs to a certain extent--each of these virtual CPUs is a thread.

Since they can save their state, a single CPU can run thousands of threads at (seemingly) the same time by stopping and restarting them thousands of times a second.

The short of it is that it's just one copy of the code but different data for each thread.

Comment: thank you for clarification :) 
Your, and @SeverityOne answer help me me a lot